# Textjoin in a sequence within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to textjoin a range with a delimiter:

[image: example]

Is there a way to textjoin this into a sequence every 3 cells within a range

I know I can do it with: A1&B1&C1&"-" etc. but my range is too great for that A until XXX and I need to ignore blank cells within that range

Comment: =A1&B1&C1&" "&D1&E1&F1&" "&G1&H1&I1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple:

```
=TEXTJOIN({"","","-"},TRUE,A1:I1)
```

[image: xlsx]

Comment: Seriousl thx! i have been breaking m head on this for dayys now

Comment: Haven't seen an array been parsed in the 1st parameter of `TEXTJOIN()` before. Makes perfect sense though. +

Comment: Interesting, sometimes it is not documented specific use cases, but the case of more than one delimiter is documented by Microsoft. See [TEXTJOIN documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) see Example 3.

Comment: Learned something new with that multiple delimiters.